# Actualizar un registro en una tabla y a partir de esto crear un registro en otra tabla

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Tengo una tabla llamada productos, y cuando selecciono un producto, se debe descontar de ese producto de la tabla producto y se debe crear un registro en otra tabla llamada carrito

las tablas del esquema son:
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170623134129) do

```
create_table "carritos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "producto_id"
    t.float    "precio"
  end

  create_table "productos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "cantidad_existencia"
    t.text     "nombre"
    t.text     "descripcion"
    t.float    "precio"
  end
```

### los modelos son:

```
class Producto < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :carrito
end

class carrito  < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :producto
end
```

### el controlador es:

```
def ajustar
  @producto.cantidad_existencia -= 1 # se resta de la cantidad de productos
  @producto.update(ajustar_producto)
end
```

### en el modelo producto creo que deberia ir esta logica, pero no hace nada.

```
class Producto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carrito

  after_save :subir_al_carrito

  private
    def subir_al_carrito
      Carrito.producto_id = self.id # id de la tabla producto
      Carrito.precio      = self.precio # precio de la tabla producto
      Carrito.save
    end
end
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es correcto, la lógica debería ir en el modelo, pero necesitas ajustar el código del método `subir_al_carrito` para crear el registro:

```
def subir_al_carrito
  Carrito.create!(producto_id: id, precio: precio)
end
```

El método creará un nuevo registro en `Carrito` con el `id` y `precio` del producto. Como podrás ver, no hace faltar utilizar `self` para leer los valores de los atributos (solo es necesario cuando los asignas).

Comment: Sigue sin agregar el registro :(

Comment: @rrg1459 ¿Qué te muestra el log? ¿El producto sí se está actualizando?

Comment: Listo, tenia un end mal colocado, si lo hace ,una pregunta adicional, que funcion cunple el admiracion ! justo despues del create?

Comment: @rrg1459 `create!` genera un error (excepción) cuando el registro falla, al contrario de `create`, el cual simplemente no crea el registro pero no genera error. Dado que lo estás creando en tu modelo, es mejor utilizar `create!` pues tu flujo nunca espera que la creación del registro falle. Haz la prueba en la consola de rails, y verás el resultado.

Comment: Excelene, gracias Gerry